# How to fix bug of JFileChooser or avoid the bug preventing JFC to show shortcut (lnk) folders

Tags: java, swing, directory, jfilechooser, lnk

Using NetBeans(java) I created a JDialog with a JFileChooser and when I try to open a lnk folder using the ComboBox (in other ways works fine) an exception is thrown and the folder is not opened.
I found out that is a [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6672017):
I tried some workarounds but they didn't work.
Can you help me?
Alternatively, can you suggest me a "trick"?
I thought about prevent the JFileChooser(or at least the ComboBox) to show lnk folders but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What about using a `FileSystemView` to filter out the links, as suggested in the 'possible workaround' at the bottom of the bug report?

Comment: I already tried the workaround. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can either prevent the symlinks to be displayed by using a [`FileFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html) and the `FileUtils` from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#isSymlink%28java.io.File%29):

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "All (without symlinks)";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File f) {
        try {
            return !FileUtils.isSymlink(f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return true; // Maybe to be changed to false depending on
                         // your use case
        }
    }
});
```

An other alternative is to use a custom [`FileSystemView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html), as @Andrew Thompson suggested.

**EDIT**:
After reading your question more carefully, it looks like you more interested in filtering the Windows shortcuts. The same technique applies:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "All (without shortcuts)";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File f) {
        return !f.getName().endsWith(".lnk");
    }
});
```